# Occurrences of a value in a table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, pubmed

I got articles from PubMed, I am using Power BI to visualise How many articles are written by each author, each article is written by many authors as shown in the picture any idea to do that, this is my table structure in power bi. What I want to get is a chart visualising :

> name of author: number of articles

One other thing is to visualise collaboration between authors, I mean how many time each pair of authors worked together,
any ideas, I searched about it but not result that I need just an orientation.

[image: picture of data]

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to show how many article writes a specific author then you need a list of authors in one column (if you dont have dictionary then you can create this list as NewTable in dax):

```
AuthorsList = SUMMARIZE(UNION( VALUES(pubmed[name1]), VALUES(pubmed[name2]), VALUES(pubmed[name3])), pubmed[name1])
```

Then we can create a measure:

```
ArticleCount = 
var __author = SELECTEDVALUE(AuthorsList[name1])
return
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES(pubmed[ID])), FILTER(ALL(pubmed), pubmed[name1] = __author || pubmed[name2] = __author || pubmed[name3] = __author))
```

[image]

And for collaboration, I think we can create a cross join ListOfAuthors and use measures like this one (but I don't test it).

```
ArticleCount = 
var __author = SELECTEDVALUE(AuthorsList[name1])
var __author2 = SELECTEDVALUE(AuthorsList[name2])
var __author3 = SELECTEDVALUE(AuthorsList[name3])
return
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES(pubmed[ID])), FILTER(ALL(pubmed), 
(pubmed[name1] = __author || pubmed[name2] = __author || pubmed[name3] = __author)    &&
(pubmed[name1] = __author2 || pubmed[name2] = __author2 || pubmed[name3] = __author2) &&
(pubmed[name1] = __author3 || pubmed[name2] = __author3 || pubmed[name3] = __author3)
)
```

)

Comment: thanks for replying, I will try this, but there is a problem wich is that there are not just 3 authors , each article has its number of authors, and it can arrive to 64 authors ... , columns are like this : Author.auth1.name     Auth.auth2.name....... is there any way to loop on them, @msta42a